# How do I retrieve a specific neo4j node property using neo4jclient?

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I have some data stored as a neo4j node. This node has some property that is not described by the associated C# class, and thus is not automatically mapped back to the class when the neo4jclient query returns.

As an example, this C# class:

```
public class Node {
    public string name;
    public int number;
    public CustomClass data;
}
```

stored in neo4j, then retrieved with the following neo4jclient fluent code:

```
var query = client.Cypher
    .Match("(n:Node)")
    .Return(n => n.As<Node>())
    .Results;
```

will populate a Node object with name and number, but leave a null reference to the CustomClass object.

To solve this problem I have serialized the CustomClass as a JSON string, and stored it in neo4j as a string property. In order to deserialize this JSON class, I need to retrieve the JSON string property from the Node stored in neo4j.

The neo4jclient documentation recommends the following:

```
.Return(() => new {
    JSONString = Return.As<string>("matchedNode.JSONProperties")
})
```

<s>however this is invalid code. The `Return` after `JSONString =` does not exist in that context.</s>

**See Answer.**

How can I get the JSONPropeties string out of the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given code works exactly as expected, you just need to include the correct neo4jclient reference. In this case it is

```
using Neo4jClient.Cypher;
```

with that, `Return` is no longer undefined. This is also where the `All` class is, if you need access to all matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

Further to your answer, aside from adding the

`using Neo4jClient.Cypher`

You could also choose just to return the `Node` properties like so:

```
var query = client.Cypher
    .Match("(n:Node)")
    .Return(n => n.As<Node>().name) //<-- returning just the property
    .Results;
```

Comment: This works only if the class specified in the .As<> call has a field that matches the neo4j node field. (In your example "name".) But my issue as stated was that "This node has some property that is not described by the associated C# class..." so this answer is not applicable.

Comment: I would then use `Node<string>` and cast to a `dynamic` object